# Update Already opened Google Map by sending new destination address from our service

Tags: android, google-maps

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + strlat + "," + strlon + "&daddr=" + strDlat + "," + strDlon;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setComponent((new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity")));
startActivity(intent);
```

This code opens a google map and We can navigate to the destination address without any problem.
My Question is if the destination address also keeps changing (say user 2 is moving to another location and I have the location) how can we update that on google map?
Is there any way to inform google map that please update the destination location too.
I don't want to add google map in my activity. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't inform Google Maps about location changes. It will automatically track user location.

However, you can only pass one location (e.g. destination) and let user decide what to do with it.

Comment: is there any library to do so?

Comment: I have never heard of such a library. If you want to have full control I advise to implement Google Maps inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot update the google map started by the following code

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + strlat + "," + strlon + "&daddr=" + strDlat + "," + strDlon;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setComponent((new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity")));
startActivity(intent);`
```

I have acheived this task by 
1. create GoogleMapActivity with a map
2. draw markers two markers on it with lat,long
3. get dirctions 
using following code
`

```
 private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

              // Origin of route
              String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

              // Destination of route
              String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

              // Sensor enabled
              String sensor = "sensor=false";

              // Building the parameters to the web service
              String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

              // Output format
              String output = "json";

              // Building the url to the web service
              String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
       Log.i("MAP", "url="+url);
              return url;
          }
          /** A method to download json data from url */
          private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
              String data = "";
              InputStream iStream = null;
              HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
              try{
                  URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                  // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();;
                  urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                  urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                  // Connecting to url
                  urlConnection.connect();

                  // Reading data from url
                  iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                  String line = "";
                  while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                      sb.append(line);
                  }

                  data = sb.toString();

                  br.close();

              }catch(Exception e){
                  Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
              }finally{
                  iStream.close();
                  urlConnection.disconnect();
              }
              return data;
          }
`
```

then draw the lines on google map